# Gitlab CI: Get last commit hash on master when merging with an other branch

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci, cicd

I need to get the list of files modified between the last commit on main and the last commit of a MR when the branch linked to it is going to be merged into main.

In addition, the list of modified files should only consist of files that have been modified/added from the branch in question to main.

For example, let's say I've created an MR on a project, made all the changes I want and merge the associated branch into main. Let's say the diffs between main and my-branch are the following:

Present on main but not on my-branch:

- README.md
- doc/

Present on my-branch but not on main:

- source/test1.c
- source/test2.c
- source/test3.c

Then I expect to get only the test.c files.

To do this, I know I can use the `git diff --name-only ${first_commit}..${CI_COMMIT_SHA}` command to get the differences in a pipeline **when the merge into main occurs**. But I don't know how to get the variable **first_commit**, which is the hash of the last commit made on main. I know that from a branch I can get this hash like this: `git cherry -v origin/main` but this will of course not work when the merge happens.

**Update 1:**

I didn't mention all the attempts I made but one is the predefined variables as suggested by @sytech, some variables that I tried to use seem to be undefined:

[image: screenshot]

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Maybe you're looking for `CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_SHA` ? See [predefined variables](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html) for more info.

Comment: @sytech Hi, thanks but I already tried to use those variables, I updated the post with it

Comment: You need to [configure merge request pipelines](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/merge_request_pipelines.html), it seems. Otherwise, you're just running a branch pipeline that has no context of the MR or target.

Comment: I don't think it's the correct solution, since the pipeline must be triggered when the merge is going to be done on main, so the variables you are talking about, are not defined in this context in my opinion

Comment: I see. Right, if you want this for the branch pipeline that occurs **after** the merge, you might be able to use `$CI_COMMIT_BEFORE_SHA`